# PDF Preview not working

Tags: lyx, viewers, acrobat

I'm using LyX 1.6.8 on Windows 7 Pro x64. Today I installed Adobe Reader X - and it doesn't work with LyX any more: Adobe Reader does not open the generated PDF after you created the PDF with LyX. It only shows a welcome dialog like "Open last files - Acrobat services - etc".

First idea of course was "file association" - But the pdf file association is alright. Double clicking a pdf works from any place (also paths with spaces).

Anyone having ideas? Confirmthis? Maybe related to some 64 bit thing?

Comment: If its possible to send a Minimum Working Example we can diagnose the problem. Check with  sumatrapdf viewer downloadable at http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html. Its good for latex needs.

Comment: Note that Reader locks open files for editing; LaTeX will throw an error if it can't write to the file.

Comment: I had a problem when I updated my reader, here's the solution I found from
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243899/lyx-view-pdflatex-does-not-display-automatically-in-acrobat-pro-dc) replacing the file pdfview.exe [with this one](http://ftp.lyx.de/LyX%202.1.3/pdfview.exe)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Acrobat Reader’s Edit/Preferences/General and un-check the box at the bottom that says “Enable Protected Mode at startup”.

Or use a better PDF viewer such as [Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) which works well with LaTeX and can synchronise TeX source and PDF.

Comment: In Adobe Acrobat XI, it's Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced) > Protected View (Off)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you need to add the proper path to Adobe Reader in settings. Tools->Preferences->Paths and append the path to Adobe Reader. See the current path string that is already there and apply the same syntax (path1;path2;path3).

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps:

1. Close your running Lyx
2. Open any PDF file within your computer with "right-click" - open with -> choose your Adobe Acrobat as default. Close the PDF file.
3. Open Lyx - Tool - Preferences - Path - PATH Prefix
4. From many paths listed, Change ONLY the path of Ghostscript to your Adobe Acrobat path. Apply - Save
5. Tools - Reconfigure, close Lyx
6. Reopen your Lyx file :D

DONE !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.